# Are there any good exercise to practice the programming logic of iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've been learning how to develop iOS for about 3 months now. Just wonder if there are any good programming exercises to learn about the programming logic in objective-c. Like some challenging questions with solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Personally, I think I get most of my practice (other than my ongoing projects) from trying to answer Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: Take up any project and try to do it on your own, i found it be very useful for [quick learning](http://way2ios.com) of iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest challenge you can have is a project for an actual client with **deadlines**. If you don't have a client, just propose yourself a project (an RSS Reader, is normally asked in iOS interviews) and set a deadline for it.